# Nexus S GPS reception quality has dropped : Can it be fixed?

Tags: gps, samsung-nexus-s

My Nexus S GPS unit seems to function more poorly every week.  Sometimes I can't get a lock at  all: using a GPS monitor shows it perpetually stuck at three satellites.  I frequently loose GPS coverage when moving on my bicycle, a car, or even walking with the phone held above my head.  Is there a fix beyond replacing the entire phone?

Comment: If it opens, question should be migrated to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60741/mobile-devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading and trying a number of Internet tutorials on the subject, I found a simpler answer.  The screws were loose.

Turns out the Nexus S GPS antenna is dependent on getting a good connection between the two halves of the case.  Tightening up the screws in the image did the trick.  These screws control the pressure on the antenna contact and provide a ground connection between the two case halves:

[image: Nexus S GPS Fix]

Loosening the screws resulted in poor GPS performance again.

Other tutorials have you bending contacts, soldering and/or adding a second internal antenna.  It's possible the writers simply screwed the case on tight after making otherwise ineffective changes.

Opening the case to clean the contacts may also help.

Comment: This is basic `cell phone 101`.  The cell phone must have a good reception of the signal.  Apple experience an "AttenaGate` back a few years because people were holding their phone wrong.